# How do I run an accurate but (relatively) simple task scheduler on ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, timer, shared-hosting, jobs, job-scheduling

There are many posts on running scheduled tasks on ASP.Net. Most involve using the HTTP cache expiry (which is not really an elegant solution) and not very reliable or very accurate.

Others recommend that the best way is to have a service running on the server designed explicitly for this. But what about users who are running on shared hosting and don't have the privilege to run service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last year, I found some posts on Stack Overflow to implement a Registered object as a class and implement that to run scheduled tasks. I expanded on that solution and came up with a configurable timer running on a separate thread to run scheduled tasks very well.

This has worked very well in production for the last two years. I'd like to post this solution so it can help someone... Of course, maybe someone can help improve it too...

Here goes - First, here is the main Job class... (And yes, I do prefer VB.NET)

```
Imports System.Web.Hosting

Public Class JobHost
    Implements IRegisteredObject
    Dim _ShutDown As Boolean
    Property Running As Boolean
    Property JobTimer As Threading.Timer

    ReadOnly Property ShuttingDown As Boolean
        Get
            Return _ShutDown
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(Me)
    End Sub

    Public Sub InitTimer(callback As Threading.TimerCallback, Start As Integer, period As Integer)
        _JobTimer = New Threading.Timer(callback, Nothing, Start * 1000, period * 1000)
    End Sub

    Public Sub [Stop](immediate As Boolean) Implements Web.Hosting.IRegisteredObject.Stop
        _ShutDown = True
        If _JobTimer IsNot Nothing Then _JobTimer.Dispose()
        _JobTimer = Nothing

        If immediate Then
            HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(Me)
        Else
            If Not _Running Then HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(Me)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above class implements a function called `InitTimer` that takes a callback parameter as well as Start and Period parameters. This is in seconds - but you can change it to millisec by removing the 1000 multiplier.

Next, in our `Global.asax` Application Start event, we initialize the class and create a Callback method that in turn fires methods at various intervals.

I've left a lot of original code and method calls for the purpose of illustration - you can remove them all. As you can see, I am also logging how long each group of tasks takes.

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<script runat="server">
    Private CurMin As Integer = 0
    Private iJob As JobHost, il_Start As Long

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        LogAction("System", "------ App Start ------", String.Empty, True)
        RegisterRoutes(Routing.RouteTable.Routes)
        WorkOrderClass.UpdateClosedWO()
        ConfigClass.LoadAppConfig()
        ClearActionLog(2)  ' Keep only 2 months of action logs
        InitPDF()
        If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EnableJobs") IsNot Nothing Then
            LogAction("System", "Jobs Enabled", "On Server: " & Environment.MachineName, True)
            DeleteTempFiles()
            MailSystemLog()
            DocumentClass.EnsureDocFolder()
            WorkOrderClass.UpdateAbandoned()
            DeleteEventsData()
            iJob = New JobHost
            iJob.InitTimer(AddressOf TimerCallback, 60, 10)
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub TimerCallback(state As Object)
        If iJob.Running OrElse iJob.ShuttingDown Then Exit Sub  ' Exit if previous job is already running or if application is shutting down
        If Now.Minute <> CurMin AndAlso DAL.ConnectionAvailable Then  ' Only perform tasks when minute changes and Database is available

            ' Set flag and culture
            iJob.Running = True
            Dim li_Hr As Integer = Now.ToUniversalTime.Hour
            Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")  ' Is needed to change thread culture from server culture
            CurMin = Now.ToUniversalTime.Minute

            Timer1min()   ' Fire tasks that must run every minute

            If CurMin Mod 5 = 0 Then Timer5min()   ' Fire tasks that must run every 5 minutes

            If CurMin Mod 30 = 0 Then Timer30min() ' 30 min tasks

            If li_Hr Mod 6 = 0 And CurMin = 2 Then Timer6hrs() ' 6 hourly tasks at x:02 to keep prevent same time as 5 min and 30 min tasks

            If li_Hr = 5 And CurMin = 4 Then Timer5Z() ' Tasks at 5:04am

            iJob.Running = False

        End If
    End Sub

    ' 1 Min tasks
    Private Sub Timer1min()
        WorkOrderClass.CalcBatch()
    End Sub

    ' 5 Min tasks
    Private Sub Timer5min()
        il_Start = Now.Ticks
        UpdateUsersOnline()
        POP3.CheckMail()
        LogAction("System", "Timer5min End", "Duration: " & Format((Now.Ticks - il_Start) / 10000, "#,##0") & "ms", True)
    End Sub

    ' 30 min tasks
    Private Sub Timer30min()
        il_Start = Now.Ticks
        WorkOrderClass.CheckStatusUpdates()
        WorkOrderClass.EmailAlerts()
        CusRepClass.SendReports()
        AdvRepClass.SendReports()
        SeqClass.TrackCont()
        SeqClass.SendUpdates()
        CusRepEntClass.CleanLog()
        WorkOrderClass.CreateNotify(1)
        LogAction("System", "Timer30min End", "Duration: " & Format((Now.Ticks - il_Start) / 10000, "#,##0") & "ms", True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer6hrs()
        il_Start = Now.Ticks
        WorkOrderClass.UpdateAbandoned()
        LogAction("System", "Timer6hr End", "Duration: " & Format((Now.Ticks - il_Start) / 10000, "#,##0") & "ms", True)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer5Z()  ' at 5am UTC
        DemClass.SendNotifications()
        DeleteTempFiles()
        WorkOrderClass.CreateNotify(2) ' 2=Daily notification
        WorkOrderClass.SendAbandoned(False)
        If Now.ToUniversalTime.Date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then WorkOrderClass.SendAbandoned(True)
    End Sub

   ' Other methods in Global.asax removed...
```

I've tried to put as many comments as possible. As you can see, the timer fires the first time after 60 seconds (gives enough time for the app to start-up and finish initialization methods) and then fires every 10 seconds thereafter.

If a task is already running when the timer is fired, then no new task is started - although you can change this if you like.

Of course, you need to keep your ASP.Net application alive when running tasks. Any external service that periodically pings a page on your site will keep it alive.